# Declaring system trigger names in PG 12 or PG 13

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I just noticed that constraints, such as `FOREIGN KEY`, automatically generate system triggers, and names them `RI_ConstraintTrigger_a or _c + trigger oid`. I've looked at the docs, but do not see a way to declare names for these triggers in `FOREIGN KEY`, etc.. I care because I'm writing a bit of check code to compare objects in two different databases. The local names of system triggers vary, since the oids are naturally going to vary.

Is there a way to declare names for these triggers as they're created? If so, is there some harm in doing so? I think that I read that after a restore or upgrade, the trigger and related function names might be regenerated. If so, using `RENAME TRIGGER` on these items seems like swimming upstream...and I suspect is a Bad Idea.

I suppose that I could locate a trigger's local name by querying `pg_trigger` on  combination of other attributes...but I'm not seeing what makes a trigger unique, *apart* from it's unique name. All I can think of is to search against pg_get_triggerdef(oid), and compare the outputs.

For those following along at home, here's a "hello world" example that creates a couple of system triggers.

```
DROP TABLE if exists calendar_child CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE calendar_child
(
  id                       uuid      NOT NULL DEFAULT extensions.gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
  calendar_id              uuid      NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
  );

ALTER TABLE calendar_child
    ADD CONSTRAINT calendar_year_calendar_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (calendar_id) REFERENCES calendar(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

select oid,tgrelid::regclass,tgname from pg_trigger where tgrelid::regclass::text = 'calendar_child';

+--------+----------------+-------------------------------+
| oid    | tgrelid        | tgname                        |
+--------+----------------+-------------------------------+
| 355281 | calendar_child | RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_355281 |
| 355282 | calendar_child | RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_355282 |
+--------+----------------+-------------------------------+
```

Here's a sample, lightly formatted, of what `pg_get_triggerdef` returns.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_352380" 
    AFTER DELETE ON calendar FROM calendar_year 
    NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY 
    IMMEDIATE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION "RI_FKey_cascade_del"()
```

The linked function names aren't named dynamically, they seem to be calls to C routines for standard behaviors, found in https://doxygen.postgresql.org/ri__triggers_8c_source.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported to change the name of these triggers, and there is no support for renaming triggers in general.

There is no point in comparing these trigger names, because they are just implementation details of the foreign key constraint. Constraints can be renamed, and you can get the constraint definition with the `pg_get_constraintdef` function. That is what you should compare.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `pg_constraints` and `pg_get_constraintdef()`  sound like a better place to go.`